# Exercicio com map

Tags: c++, map

Crie um `map` que possui três chaves (“`Local`”, “`Resp`”, “`Prioridade`”). Peça para o usuário preencher esse `map` e depois mostre o resultado na tela.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>


using namespace std;

int main(){

    map<string,map<string,string>> alfa;

    string local;
    string prioridade;
    string responsavel;


    cout<<"Digite o local: ";
    cin>>local;
    cout<<"Digite a prioridade: ";
    cin>>alfa[local][prioridade];
    cout<<"Digite o responsável: ";
    cin>>alfa[local][responsavel];

     for(auto elem : alfa){
        cout << elem.first << " " << elem.second[prioridade]<< " " << elem.second[responsavel]<<endl;

    }
}
```

Comment: Qual é a sua questão ?

Answer (score 0):

Um std::map possui dois campos: Chave e Valor. A chave é o identificador, a partir dela você consegue recuperar o valor associado àquela chave.

O exercício diz: `crie um map com três chaves (“Local”, “Resp”, “Prioridade”)`. Logo, você deve criar um map com 3 entradas, cujas chaves são essas listadas. O valor associado a cada chave será informado pelo usuário.

Segue o código corrigido.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

int main() {
   map<string,string> alfa;

   cout << "Digite o local: ";
   cin  >> alfa["Local"];
   cout << "Digite o responsavel: ";
   cin  >> alfa["Resp"];
   cout << "Digite a prioridade: ";
   cin  >> alfa["Prioridade"];

   for(auto& elem : alfa){
      cout << elem.first << ": " << elem.second << " " << endl;
   }
}
```